# Using Fiddler to check IIS Compression

Tags: fiddler

How do I see if IIS Compression is working using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)? I have a page that, when viewed through [Port80Software](http://www.port80software.com) or [GID Network's tool](http://www.gidnetwork.com/tools/gzip-test.php) it appears to be coming across compressed.

However, when I watch the call in Fiddler, I see the 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' in the request header, but I don't see the 'Content-Encoding: gzip' or 'deflate' in the response header. Also, in the Transformer section, 'No Compression' is selected.

Thanks!

Chris

Comment: Which session are you viewing when you see the request and response headers? Typically only text/* MIME content is compressed, so if you are looking at an image or other binary resource it probably will not be compressed.

Comment: I'm looking at an .ASHX page that returns XML (showing 'content type text/xml' in Fiddler).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I went straight to the source (to Eric Lawrence) and this is what he said:

> Indeed, Fiddler shows your site is compressing properly.
>
> Do you have an upstream proxy
>   server in your environment?  Did you
>   try this test from your home network
>   rather than your corporate network?
>
> On Microsoft’s corporate network, we
>   are all behind an ISA proxy server. 
>   It’s configured to remove the outbound
>   Accept-Encoding header (which tells
>   servers to use compression) and if a
>   compressed response is received by the
>   proxy, it’s decompressed by the ISA
>   server.  This is done so the ISA proxy
>   server can scan the content for
>   malicious data.  The downside is that
>   Fiddler is only seeing the traffic as
>   it’s received from the upstream proxy.
>
> Usually, when we need to test
>   compression and the like, we do so
>   from home or what’s called a “DTAP”—a
>   direct line to the internet that
>   doesn’t go through the proxy.

Comment: So then how do I see this on Fiddler? I'm testing on local.

Answer (score 8):

My version of fiddler has and AutoDecode button that made everything appear to have No Compression.  After turning this off, my responses showed compression

Comment: Also, if you hit the 'Decode' button, it strips the compression.  So if you decode a request to take a look at it, it now shows No Compression, even if originally it had compression.

Answer (score 5):

From the Inspectors tab, there is a group of sub -tabs.  Make sure you have Transformer selected.  Then for each request on the page load, look to see if it was sent with GZIP or No Compression.

Fiddler is pretty good and allows you to pick each individual request made when loading the file.

Comment: Cross posted an updated as you were writing this. Transformer indicates 'No Compression'

Answer (score 1):

Based on the various answers and comments, I'm going to conclude that perhaps the page itself (`text/html`) is compressed, but the `text/xml` you deliver as part of an AJAX request(?) and the other content delivered for the page is not.

As I already mentioned in a comment, you typically want to compress `text/*` (i.e. - `text/html`, `text/plain`, `text/css`, etc) and `application/javascript` & `application/ecmascript` (as per [rfc4329](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4329.txt)). If you deliver your `.js` files using some other MIME type (for example, `application/x-javascript` or `text/javascript`), compress that instead, or change the MIME type used to deliver `.js` files to the RFC standard.

See the appropriate link below for updating the MIME types being compressed on your server:

- [Using HTTP Compression On Your IIS 5.0 Web Site](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742379.aspx#EAAA)
- [Customizing the File Types IIS Compresses (IIS 6.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/5bce429d-c4a7-4f9e-a619-5972497b932a.mspx)
- [How to add content types for HTTP compression in IIS 7.0](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969062)

One last point I should make, some web browsers (in particular certain versions of Netscape 4 but there may be others) send `Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate` for CSS and JavaScript file requests, but could not actually decompress the content. Also, some versions of Internet Explorer ([5.5](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q313712) & [6](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q312496)) had problems with compression.

I know the default Apache compression configuration I used deals with these issues, I'm not sure how (or whether) IIS compensates for them.