# Compression is not working

Tags: asp.net, http, iis, compression

I need to compress all dynamic content of my data export site.
I've tried numerous ways, nothing works. Chrome shows that content is not compressed and "Content-Encoding" header is not present.

Trying to do it like this as the last resort method (before writing any response):

```
        context.Response.Filter = new DeflateStream(context.Response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
        context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "deflate");
```

Logging shows that this code is executed correctly. 
However, Chrome shows that content is not compressed, again.

UPD when using IIS built-in compression, it seems to work and request tracing shows "DYNAMIC_COMPRESSION_SUCCESS". However, IE still shows that response is not compressed. The same when I'm requesting the page from the server itself using localhost name.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you testing from the server?

Comment: @rikitikitik, you read the question, didn't you?

Comment: As ZiyaSAL points out, the browser must first indicate that it accepts compressed content. Have you checked the headers sent from the browser to the server? This related question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/897989/64096

Comment: @Marnix van Valen, obviously I did check this.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of trying to do this manually I would rely on the pre-written (and tested) Microsoft code built into IIS that will do this for you:

Install [Dynamic Content Compression on the machine](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738113%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) (bullet 5 in the link) and [enable it in IIS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753681%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). IIS will now handle compression for on both static and dynamic content. Less code to maintain (and invariably have bugs) is always a good thing!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do this manually first check the compression is supported,

```
public static bool IsGZipSupported()
{
    string AcceptEncoding = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(AcceptEncoding) &&
            (AcceptEncoding.Contains("gzip") || AcceptEncoding.Contains("deflate")))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

And compress your response,

```
public static void GZipEncodePage()
{
            if (IsGZipSupported()) {
                HttpResponse Response = HttpContext.Current.Response;

                string AcceptEncoding = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers("Accept-Encoding");
                if (AcceptEncoding.Contains("gzip")) {
                    Response.Filter = new System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(Response.Filter, System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Compress);
                    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
                } else {
                    Response.Filter = new System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream(Response.Filter, System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Compress);


            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "deflate");
}
```

You can check filter is attached just before the headers are sent to the client

```
protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders()
{
    HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
    if (response.Filter is GZipStream && response.Headers["Content-encoding"] != "gzip")
        response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "gzip");
    else if (response.Filter is DeflateStream && response.Headers["Content-encoding"] != "deflate")
        response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "deflate");
}
```

For more information check this posts;

- [ASP.NET GZip Encoding Caveats](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2011/May/02/ASPNET-GZip-Encoding-Caveats)
- [Built-in GZip/Deflate Compression on IIS 7.x](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2011/May/05/Builtin-GZipDeflate-Compression-on-IIS-7x)
- [Benefits and Drawbacks of IIS 7 Compression](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2009/02/22/iis-7-compression-good-bad-how-much.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

If you are using IIS7+, there's an Compression option. Navigate to your site, in the right main window, click "Compression", and check all 2 checkboxes:

1. Enable dynamic content compression
2. Enable static content compression