# Incorrect response from the server anfter GET request

Tags: c++, html

When I send a request with "GET" in c++ like this:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: site.com\r\n\r\n
```

I receive the proper answer. But when I configure the request according to what browsers do (I captured the headers from packet sniffer) the response from the server is 200 OK but the html body is a piece of garbage. Also the content-Length shown in the header proves that I didn't get the correct html response.
The problem occurs when adding "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate". I send exactly what the browser sends. But I receive different response than browser.
Why do you think this happens?

Comment: The server is sending back gzipped content. You need to g-unzip it for it to be readable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But as I said the "Content-Length" field in the response header for browser is different than mine. For example the browser receives "Content-Length: 17000" but I receive "Content-Length: 4000". How is it possible?

Comment: Use Fiddler to capture and compare requests/responses you are sending and what browser send.

Comment: I am exactly using Fiddler

Comment: I've never used Fiddler but searching the web shows that it has options that might be decompressing the data for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897989/using-fiddler-to-check-iis-compression

Comment: Yes. That for sure decompresses the HTML code. I don't see any other reason for receiving different content length. I should point out that I get the response header for my browser in packet sniffer but my program's response in its console window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you accept gzipped content, the server may send gzipped content. (In fact, some buggy servers send gzipped content even if you don't say you accept it!)

Notice that in the returned headers, it will include `Content-Encoding: gzip`, or maybe deflate instead of gzip. This tells you about the encoding. If it is gzipped, you need to decompress it with a library like `zlib`.

Another thing you might see in replies to HTTP 1.1 requests is that the connection won't necessarily close when it is completed, and you might get `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`, which will format the body differently. Chunked responses are a series of chunks with a hex length, then content, terminated by an empty chunk. Non-chunked responses, by contrast, are sent with a `Content-Length` header which tells you how much to expect. The content length is the length of the data it sends, which will be smaller if the data is compressed.

Unless you implement decompression, don't send `Accept-Encoding`. Chunked responses are something you'll probably have to implement though, since it is common in http 1.1 and if you do just http 1.0, you won't get to use the important host header.