# Issue in JSON webservice response compression invoking from JBOSS 4.2.3

Tags: java, jquery, json, jboss, webservice-client

Hosted Axis2 JSON web services in JBOSS Appserver and configured for response compression in connector (in server.xml file). Tested the service by Java client and received the response which is in compressed (GZIP) mode (monitored through TCP/IP monitor in eclipse).

Now the issue is, when I invoke the same web service from a jQuery client, response is not in compressed mode and received normal response instead of compressed (GZIP) mode.

Below the configuration made in JBOSS.

```
<Connector port="8080" address="${jboss.bind.address}"    
     maxThreads="250" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
     emptySessionPath="true" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
     enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
     connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" 
     compression="on"  compressionMinSize="2048" 
     noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata" compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/css,text/javascript,application/x-javascript,application/javascript,application/json;charset=UTF-8,image/svg+xml,text/json,gzip"/>
```

Below is the jQuery client

```
<title>Calling Web Service from jQuery</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="json2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 if (!window.console) console = {log: function() {}};
    $(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery.support.cors = true;
        $("#btnCallWebService").click(function (event) {
            var start = new Date().getTime();                
            var wsUrl = "http://10.191.54.97:8080/axis2/services/TestCompression?wsdl";             
            var soapRequest ="<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><soapenv:Body><ns1:Compression xmlns:ns1=\"http://www.example.org/TestCompression/\"><CompressionReq>test</CompressionReq></ns1:Compression></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>"; 
            $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
                url: wsUrl,
                contentType: "text/xml",                    
                dataType: "json",
                headers: { "Accept-Encoding" : "gzip" },
                data: soapRequest,
                success: processSuccess,
                error: processError
            });

        });
    });     
    function processSuccess (data) {        
      console.log(data);        
      var strdata = JSON.stringify(data);       
      $('#response').html(strdata);     
    }
    function processError(data, status, req) {
       alert('iam failure')
       alert(req.responseText + " " + status);
    }
</script>
```

Below response headers taken from Fiddler,

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Via: 1.1 RSI-CHE-TMG01
Connection: Keep-Alive
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Wed, 09 Apr 2014 08:42:36 GMT
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Powered-By: Servlet 2.4; JBoss-4.2.3.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_3_GA date=200807181439)/JBossWeb-2.0
```

Request you to please help me with this issue..

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got solution from below post,

[Using Fiddler to check IIS Compression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897989/using-fiddler-to-check-iis-compression)

**Solution:**

I just disabled internet proxy details in my browser. Triggered the service and now i can see the compressed response in fiddler.

Thanks.